# How to keep toolbar always on top while cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport filling the rest of the height?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have a page that contains a `mat-toolbar` and `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`. I want to keep `mat-toolbar` always on top of the screen, while `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` fills the rest of the screen.

I tried set the height of `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to `100vh`, however, when I reach the end of the list, the tool bar is gone.

Here is the sample code I prepared: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbxmce

As you can see, once we scrolled to the end of the bottom, we need to scroll back to the first item in order to make the tool bar appears again. How can I fixed the position of the tool bar while keeping the list fills the rest of the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the Toolbar's [height](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/toolbar/toolbar.scss), then you can calculate the viewport's height:

```
.example-viewport {
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  margin: 4px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to implement layout for your page and add `mat-toolbar` to the layout.

This is an example:

```
...

const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'test',
   component: TestLayoutComponent,
   children: [
     { path: '', component: TestComponent },
   ]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }
```

[Read more](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-routing-reusing-common-layout-for-pages-from-different-modules-440a23f86b57)

Comment: Also, make sure you read the comment from **Alexander Carls** in the post re [How to reuse common layouts in Angular using Router](https://medium.com/@xander.carls/hi-e8ffc7d04480)

Comment: Because my app has only one page now, so I didn't think about reusing the layout. Anyway, thanks for your information. However, `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` needs a height, what should be the height of `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` after I implement the layout?

Comment: height: calc(100vh - 64px);